# How can i change a function promise to the 'async/await' appraoch

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise, backend

I was having this code in my node app:

```
function findByCredentials(email, password) {
  
  let UserModel = this;

  return UserModel.findOne({ email }).then((userDocument) => {
    if(!userDocument) return Promise.reject();

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      bcrypt.compare(password, userDocument.password, (err, res) => {
        if(res) return res(userDocument);
        else{ rej() }
      });
    })
  })

}
```

and i wanted to convert it to the 'async/await' approach, so the result that i could achieve is:

```
async function findByCredentials(email, password){

    let UserModel = this;
    const userDocument = await UserModel.findOne({ email });    

    if(!userDocument) return Promise.reject();

    const compareResult = await bcrypt.compare(password, userDocument.password);

    if (compareResult) return userDocument;
    return Promise.reject();

}
```

is this correct or not, any links or videos for learning more about this subject? thank you!.

Comment: Instead of `return Promise.reject();` you can just `throw`. And you should throw an error object with a stack trace, not `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

It is good that you also improved on the initial code for its promisifying `bcrypt.compare`, while that method (and the rest of the bcrypt API) returns a promise when you don't provide a callack argument. This improvement has nothing to do with `async` / `await`, and should have been done in the original version as well.

One more thing can be improved: you shouldn't call `Promise.reject()` without argument. Instead throw an Error object.

```
async function findByCredentials(email, password) {
  const userDocument = this.findOne({ email });
  if (!userDocument) throw new Error("User account not found");
  const compareResult = await bcrypt.compare(password, userDocument.password);
  if (!compareResult) throw new Error("Wrong password");
  return userDocument;
}
```

NB: the actual error message may need some update, as it might not be a good idea to give away what the actual reason was for the authentication failure (unknown email identifier, or wrong password).